# Frequency characteristic of active high pass filter

Tags: active-filter

How can i see the characteristic(frequency response) of an active high pass filter?I attached the circuit and the value of resistance .Can i see it on the computer without an oscilloscope ?How can i calculate it on the paper? Thank you very much[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYEdF.png)

Answer (score 0):

High frequency gain will be 1 + R3/R2. Low frequency gain will be unity. The frequency in the spectrum where the gain is changing between the two limits will be approximately \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi R_2 C_1}\$.

If frequency rises too high gain will fall-back towards zero due to inability of op-amp to perform. This is going to be totally dependent on the choice of op-amp.

Comment: ok ,thank you.Is  there  aposibility to see this on a graph? using just my computer?I don't have an oscilscope.

Comment: Why not download a (free) version of LTSpice and simulate it. All sims will show a bode plot of amplitude against frequency.

Comment: I like this site for plottting filter results  http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/CRhikeisan.htm  There are links for various active filters at the bottom of the page.